# Apply styles for several class which ends at a number

Tags: html, css

I have a doubt about this. Is it possible to apply styles to several classes which are between an interval of number? For instance, I have several divs with the class "content1", "content2", "content3", etc. In a normal case, perhaps you could do:

```
.content1, content2, content3{
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

Or:

```
div[class^="content"]{
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

But it is posibble to do something like this?

```
div.content:nth-child(1-6){
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

Comment: you can use it by its parent div like .parentdiv class > div{ font-size: 1em;}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, **it is**.

Use [nth-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-of-type)

```
div[class^="content"]:nth-of-type(n+2):nth-of-type(-n+6){
   font-size: 1em;
}
```

Working **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wpvvazzs/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested looking at *CSS preprocessors*.

**SCSS**

```
@for $i from 1 through 6 {
  .content#{$i} { font-size: 1em; }
}
```

Live example [here](http://sassmeister.com/gist/7273861).

or **LESS**

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
div[class^="content"]:nth-child(-n+4) {...} /* Which will target the first 4 elements
```

Which will result in:

```
<div class="content1">This item will be selected</div>
<div class="content2">This item will be selected</div>
<div class="content3">This item will be selected</div>
<div class="content4">This item will be selected</div>
<div class="content5">...</div>
<div class="content6">...</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't target an element based on a numerical index within it's class name.

There are ways in which you could go about it (see nth-child answers) however these would fail where **N** in contentN doesn't correspond to the element's actual index.

Easily the best solution would be to add *the same* class ('content' sounds fitting) to all your elements and select using that. That's what classes are there for.